# How can I differentiate between UNIX socket connections in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, uuid

When creating a simple server to listen on a UNIX domain socket…

```
var server = require("net").createServer();
server.listen("/tmp/whatever.sock"); // Listen at UNIX domain socket
server.on("connection", function(stream) {

    // What now?

});
```

…what uniquely identifies that `stream` when it hits the `"connection"`-callback?

When working with [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets), I'm used to creating a `var clients = {}` and storing streams in it by the IP-and-port the connection originated from.

What's the equivalent "IP-and-port" unique identifier for a UNIX-domain socket and how can I see it from Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*File descriptors* are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644251/how-do-unix-domain-sockets-differentiate-between-multiple-clients) the "IP+port-equivalent" UNIX socket connection identifiers.

A Node `stream` corresponding to a UNIX socket connection has `stream._handle.fd` containing that file descriptor.

Comment: I'm aware that `_`-prefixed keys are often used in JavaScript to mean "private" fields. Does anyone know of a cleaner actually API-specified way to access the FD?