# Nodes running the same gRpc server does not need a port for inter-process communication

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, ipc

I've a process that has to be spawned on demand whenever a specific event occurs.
That process practically hosts a gRpc server, which communicate with its client (the relation is 1-1 so one client served by one server hosted in a disposable process.

My question is.. since the grpc communicate with its client using an Inter-process communication protocol transport, do I force to specify a port at all?
Because my problem here is that I cannot run more than one instance of the gRpc server since the port binding cannot be established if it's busy with a previously created instance.

Comment: If you don't need ports then why it fails with port binding error? What are you using for inter-process communication?

Comment: @Evk I'm using unix socket domain as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/interprocess?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: And you are using different sockets (socket files) for each instance?

Comment: @Evk yes, differnt files for each client.

Comment: Then I persnonally don't see what port binding cannot be established here...

Comment: Is it correct though to use different sockets for each instance? I also implemented the UNIX socket domain from the MS docs, though I only used it with one client concurrently. The way it is defined in the docs, the Kestrel only listens to one socket at a time, why not communicate with multiple clients over this socket? Check out this SO post on [how UNIX domain sockets differentiate between multiple clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644251/how-do-unix-domain-sockets-differentiate-between-multiple-clients).